# Matrices whose all principal $k\times k$ sub-matrices are positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I would like to know whether the set of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices  whose all ${{n}\choose{k}}$ principal $k\times k$ sub-matrices---the matrices obtained by removing $n-k$ columns as well as the corresponding rows---are positive semidefinite is a well-studied set, and if so under which name. This is for a given $1\leq k\leq n$. If $k=1$, this is the set of $n\times n$ matrices whose diagonal entries are non-negative, and, if $k=n$, it is the set of $n\times n$ positive-semidefinite matrices. I am interested in what is known for the general case $1\leq k\leq n$, in particular for the non-trivial case $1<k<n$, for $n\geq 3$.

Answer (score 2):

RC Thompson had a series of problems exploring questions regarding principal minors of Hermitian matrices in full:

[Principal submatrices of normal and Hermitian matrices](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256055111)

[Principal submatrices II: The upper and lower quadratic inequalities](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379568900050)

[Principal submatrices III: Linear inequalities](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/72B/jresv72Bn1p7_A1b.pdf)

[Principal submatrices IV. On the independence of the eigenvalues of different principal submatrices](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379569900378)

[Principal submatrices V: Some results concerning principal submatrices of arbitrary matrices](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/72B/jresv72Bn2p115_A1b.pdf)

[Principal submatrices VI. Cases of equality in certain linear inequalities](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437956990038X)

[Principal submatrices VII: Further results concerning matrices with equal principal minors](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/72B/jresv72Bn4p249_A1b.pdf)

[Principal submatrices. VIII. Principal sections of a pair of forms](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250131662)

[Principal submatrices IX: Interlacing inequalities for singular values of submatrices](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379572900134)

Comment: It is unclear to me if this answers the question (I am not saying it does not). Did Thompson consider matrices with positive principal k-minors? If so, in which of the 9 papers you listed? If so, what did he prove about them?

Comment: For example in the second paper he discusses lower and upper quadratic bounds on the eigenvalues of the matrix based on the eigenvalues of the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrices. Positivity can be derived from these inequalities.

Comment: Dear @NickR , many thanks for your contribution. There are some results in those papers that might turn out to be useful, but I am not sure your answer is what I was hoping for, exactly because of the generality of some of the results there, and of the specialization of some other ones. It seems more like a starting point to attack the specific problem I am interested in, rather than a direct analysis of it.